# Stripe API and ApplePay "Billing Address Invalid" issue

Tags: php, stripe-payments, applepay

I am using this code to create Stripe checkout:

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'customer_email' => 'my_test_email@gmail.com',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
            'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'unit_amount' => 1000,
                'product_data' => [
                    'name' => 'Balance top-up',
                ],
            ],
            'quantity' => 1,
                ]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'client_reference_id' => $clientReferenceId,
            'success_url' => 'https://example.com/user-deposit/?result=success',
            'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/user-deposit/?result=failed',
            'metadata' => [
                'user_id' => '1',
            ],
]);
```

Everything works fine, but if I try to pay with ApplePay from the mobile browser - I got such an error (although everything is fine with this card and the billing address is filled in in the Apple account settings):

[image]

What should I do? In fact, I don't want to ask my users for the billing address, could I use some stored info (like country and city) to pass to this API request, or perhaps I could somehow force Stripe to do not ask for billing/shipping addresses (I do not sell goods, just for top-up an internal balance in my service)?

Comment: This looks to be a problem with the card stored in Apple Wallet and not Stripe, I'd reach out to either your bank or Apple about this.

Comment: @PaulAsjes I don't think so, because I have 4 cards on my Apple Wallet and all of these throw this error. In addition, when I pay, for example, in any application (in-app purchases) - it works fine, without any troubles.

Comment: did u find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @dagger As they explained to me in Stripe support, it depends on the specific card, or rather the bank. For example, my Wise (ex-TransferWise) MasterCard works perfectly with ApplePay on Stripe.